# types as parameters in coq

Tags: polymorphism, coq, dependent-type, parametric-polymorphism

I found this code on this [stackexchange post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/114640/why-does-coq-include-let-expressions-in-its-core-language) and I'm confused about why it works. In particular,

```
Inductive Vector {A : Type} : nat -> Type :=
| nil : Vector 0
  | cons : forall n, A -> Vector n -> Vector (S n).

(* This works. *)
Check (let n := 0 in cons n 42 nil).
```

In the check, is 42 being bound to A? Doesn't A have to be a type? I tried replacing 42 with things that obviously are types,  like 'bool' or 'Type', and those worked too. That makes sense to me. But how does 42 typecheck there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A` is an [implicit argument](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/gallina-extensions.html#implicit-arguments) for `Vector`, which (by default) is inherited by the constructor `cons`. This is indicated by the curly brackets around `A : Type` in `Inductive Vector {A : Type} : nat -> Type`.

Thus, in `cons n 42 nil`, `cons` is applied to some implicit type `?A`, the natural number `n`, the element of type `?A` `42` and the `Vector 0` `nil`. Since `42` has type `nat`, `?A` can be inferred to be `nat`.